# Typescript: Exclude checks on library folders

Tags: typescript, angular

I am running an Angular 2 project with typescript and I am having many errors coming from my angular web-modules

```
[error] node-modules\webjars\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts:80: TS2304 Cannot find name 'Set'.
[error]     rawClass: string | string[] | Set<string> | {
[error]                                   ^
[error] node-modules\webjars\@angular\common\src\facade\async.d.ts:33: TS2304 Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[error]     static fromPromise(promise: Promise<any>): Observable<any>;
[error]                                 ^
[error] node-modules\webjars\@angular\common\src\facade\async.d.ts:34: TS2304 Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[error]     static toPromise(obj: Observable<any>): Promise<any>;
[error]
```

Obviously, I don't want my typescript to check these libraries, thus I have set up my `tsconfig.json` as followed :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators":true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny":true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch":true,
    "noImplicitReturns":true,
    "outDir": "./target/ts"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "project/target",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "target/web"
  ]
}
```

Is there anything else I should be doing ?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure why in the [**angular 2 quickstart**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files) `tsconfig.json` they removed the `exclude` parameter. But yes, you are right. That's all you should be doing. The `exclude` used to look like this and in my mind, should still look like this:

*tsconfig.json*

```
...
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings/globals"
]
```

Comment: What's even weirder is that it used to work fine, and the issue did appear when I upgraded from beta-17 to rc.4

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by adding back :

```
.../angular2/typings/browser.d.ts in my typings.d.ts
```

What I don't get though, is that this file is coming from angular2 (which is part of the beta-17) and I don't find any thing corresponding to this in the latest rc (4).